# Cancan authorization in Non RESTful controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a controller like this, but no model class backing it.

```
class UserInviteController < ApplicationController  
  def process_email  
     authorize! :process_email, :abc  
     ...
     method body
     ...
  end
end
```

In my ability class, I have

```
can :process_email, :abc if user.role == 1
```

I am following the wiki **[Non RESTful Controllers authorization by Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers)** and it says that you can **pass a symbol as the second argument to both authorize! and can.**

**It doesn't have to be a model class or instance.**

Generally the first argument is the "action" one is trying to perform
and
the second argument is the "subject" the action is being performed on. It can be anything.

I have done the same, but still It doesn't work.
NOTE: I also tried doing it the other way round by

```
authorize_resource :class => false
```

as said in the wiki, but that also doesn't work.

If its of any help, my controller doesn't have any actions like show, new, create or any other basic CRUD actions.
Cancan: 1.4.1

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Or does the authorize! method seem to just not fire?

Comment: @raidfire: The authorize method just doesn't seem to fire. There are no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to debug following the link [Debugging Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities) and figured out what was wrong.

The abilities were correct, I was doing a small mistake by specifying them in the wrong order.

For others coming on to this page, if you face any problems with Cancan abilities not working, try to debug using the above link. You will eventually figure out whats not working and why.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! How was the ordering wrong exactly? You have `:process_email, :abc` in both your code examples.

Comment: will you please tell what is the correct order of abilities? i m facing same porblem

Comment: @AnilD: Without looking at your problem, I really can't help you much. Post a question regarding the same, or you can get in touch with me via email, as you wish so.

Comment: @jatin , thanks for your reply but my problem is solved, i used "authorize! :vendor_transaction, :vendor_reports" in controller/action then "can :vendor_transaction, :vendor_reports" in ability class and it works, thanks